# [Ubuntu 20.04]DevCenter start with error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/stylesheets/StyleSheet

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-20.04

When I trying to run DevCenter 1.6.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. I get an errors has occurred. Then I go to .devcenter/.metadata/.log and that the log. Anyone how to fix that, please help me. Thank you so much.

```
    !SESSION 2020-08-03 15:17:46.499 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.8
java.vendor=Ubuntu
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -data @user.home/.devcenter

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2020-08-03 15:17:47.433
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-08-03 15:17:48.159
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/stylesheets/StyleSheet
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getCSSSWTEngine(ThemeEngineManager.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getEngineForDisplay(ThemeEngineManager.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createThemeEngine(PartRenderingEngine.java:1428)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1281)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.stylesheets.StyleSheet cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.100.v20140424-2042
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 5):

DevCenter is in the maintenance mode for a long time, and it was designed to work with Java 7, max 8, so it won't work with Java 11 that you have.  The workaround is to install Java 8 and use it for DevCenter.  Another possibility is to use [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) that has support for Cassandra - although it may not have full functionality of DevCenter, it should be quite close to it, plus supports work with other technologies, like, Spark, etc.  I recommend to take Zeppelin 0.9.0-preview2 that was released last week and has a [lot of improvements there regarding Cassandra support](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/new-functionality-of-cassandra.html).

Answer (score 1):

As DevCenter is using Eclipse IDE you can specify the `-vm` binary jdk library in the `devcenter.ini` file just like with Eclipse IDE. 
I have solved it by adding the following:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
```